# Random Invalid mime type error in Java Rest API

Tags: java, spring, rest, http-headers, mime-types

I have a Spring Boot application serving a Rest API.

When invoked it will sometimes not respond ("no response from server") and all I could find in the logs is the following:

> 2017-09-25 13:15:58.152 ERROR 28361 --- [o-8080-exec-245] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [
>   dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.
>   InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "*/*\r\nAccept-Language: zh-cn\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Apple
>   WebKit/537.36 (KHTML": wildcard type is legal only in '*/*' (all mime types)] with root cause
>
> org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "*/*\r\nAccept-Language: zh-cn\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Wind
>   ows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML": wildcard type is legal only in '*/*' (all mime types)
>           at org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.java:264) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELE
>   ASE]
>           at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:449) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaTypes(MediaType.java:476) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
>           at

I have attempted to use it via postman, swagger and curl, with random behaviour.

What could be the problem?.

Thanks.